# Match regex with unordered string of alphabets and numbers

Tags: python, regex

I have product names for which I have to find the model numbers. For example

```
KIPOR KDE38SS3 DIESEL 400V AGGREGAATTI # Result --> KDE38SS3 
KIPOR KDE28SS3 DIESEL 400V AGGREGAATTI # Result --> KDE28SS3 
KIPOR KDE19STA3  19 KW GENERAATTORI 400V # Result --> KDE19STA3  
KRÄNZLE C895-1 KUUMAVESIPESURI KELALLA # Result --> C895-1
KRÄNZLE 1165-1 KUUMAVESIPESURI KELALLA # Result --> 1165-1
NILFISK MH 4M-200/960 FA KUUMAVESIPESURI # Result --> MH 4M-200/960 FA
WALLIUS LMP-452i MIG HITSAUSKONE # Result --> LMP-452i
KRÄNZLE C15/150 KUUMAVESIPESURI KELALLA # Result --> C15/150
```

My current code is simple and work in some cases but I want to get an efficient way.

```
for i in range (10):
    modelnum = re.findall(r'\w+\d+\w+', productnames[i])
    print(modelnum)
```

Results:

```
['KDE38SS3', '400V']
['KDE28SS3', '400V']
['KDE19STA3Â', '400V']
['C895']
['1165']
['200', '960']
['452i']
['C15', '150']
```

Is there a way I can only parse model no. because in the results I am also getting 400V which is not a model no. and also one model no. is broken in two elements.

Comment: is your input example just a text?

Comment: unless there's a way to distinguish model number that would reject `400V` but reject `1165-1`, then no.

Comment: The model is exactly what comes after `-->`?

Comment: Okay. Can I get at least the correct model numbers ? For eg. 4th example `C895-1` and 7th example `LMP-452i` and 8th example `C15/150`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using a capturing group, and the model number is always the first match in the line, then you could do something like this:

```
for i in range (10):
    modelnum = re.findall(r'^.*?(\w+\d+\w+)', productnames[i])
    print(modelnum)
```

Comment: Can I get at least the correct model numbers ? For eg. 4th example `C895-1` and 7th example `LMP-452i` and 8th example `C15/150`.

Comment: I could certainly come up with a pattern which would work with this particular example input data, but I doubt that would be much use to you.  In order to do it right, you need to be able to specify the exact format of a valid model number, or you need to be able to specify the exact format of whatever comes before or after a model number.  Since I don't know what either of those rules would be, and since you haven't provided them, there isn't enough information to solve your problem.

Comment: It can start with any number or character `^\w` and ends with `\w` and it can have special characters in between like `[/-,.]` and you can see it in the above examples. For now we can ignore the spaces because that will include the whole string in it I guess. Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: In that case, you could use ^.*?(\d\S+|\w(?=\S*\d)\S+)

Comment: Thanks. Still there are cases which are missing but I think I can take it forwards from here.